# 22.04 update manager hangs waiting for authorization

Tags: update-manager, authentication

This used to work on this system, now it doesn't.

Ubuntu 22.04

When I run the gnome update-manager tool (aka Software Update), it hangs waiting for authorization.  I am in the sudo group.  In the past, it would bring up an authorization window, I would enter my password and it would work.  Now it never brings up the authorization window.  This also occurs with other packages, such as "Software and Updates", and at least once trying to reboot the system from the gnome interface.

Right now, I get stuff done by running it from the command line with sudo:
"sudo update-manager"

It is however irritating and I would like to know how to go back to the earlier behavior and why it changed at some point.  Was there a bad update?  Was it a security change and there is now some other preferred method?